# Discord Bot Defer Reply in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, discord

This is my code. Only the important information is given

```js
// const { clientId, guildId, token, publicKey } = require('./config.json');
require('dotenv').config()
const APPLICATION_ID = process.env.APPLICATION_ID 
const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN 
const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY || 'not set'


const axios = require('axios')
const express = require('express');
const { InteractionType, InteractionResponseType, verifyKeyMiddleware } = require('discord-interactions');

const app = express();
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

const discord_api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://discord.com/api/',
  timeout: 3000,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Authorization",
    "Authorization": `Bot ${TOKEN}`
  }
});




app.post('/interactions', verifyKeyMiddleware(PUBLIC_KEY), async (req, res) => {
  const interaction = req.body;

  if (interaction.type === InteractionType.APPLICATION_COMMAND) {

    if(interaction.data.name == 'chat'){
        
        return res.send({
          type: InteractionResponseType.DEFFERED_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        });
        //do stuff
        //update message here
    }

}
});


//commands defined here

  try
  {
    // api docs - https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#create-global-application-command
    let discord_response = await discord_api.put(
      `/applications/${APPLICATION_ID}/commands`,
      slash_commands
    )
    console.log(discord_response.data)
    return res.send('commands have been registered')
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e.code)
    console.error(e.response?.data)
    return res.send(`${e.code} error from discord`)
  }
})
```

This defers the interaction received from discord, but how can I update my message after it finishes processing? I have searched online a lot but most of the information I get is about gateways. How can I achieve this through http and axios? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just above the `DEFERED_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE` in the docs is how you send a regular message (`CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE`), but by sending this you will end up attempting to reply to an already replied message (defers count as replies) - this will return an error which is not as we want!

Thus, you can edit the message using the [Edit Original Interaction Response Endpoint](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#create-global-application-command)! Send along a PATCH request to the endpoint, similarly to how you responded to your interaction in the first place. This endpoint allows you to pass the same JSON information as the EditWebhookMessage endpoint (See [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#edit-webhook-message-jsonform-params)) including content and any embeds you wish to send. This could look something like this...

See the [list of following up](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#followup-messages) options for more info.
Happy coding!